# Bug? Side effects when exporting to .mx

Tags: export, version-10, associations

I seem to have encountered a bug when exporting to .mx, at least on OS X. Can anyone reproduce this? I am on MMA 10, OS X 10.9.4.

```
assoc = <|"a" -> Today, "b" -> {<|"c" -> 1, "d" -> 2|>, <|"c" -> 3,"d" -> 4|>}|>
```

[image]

```
Export["mx.mx",assoc];
assoc
```

[image]

But if instead I issue

```
Export["wdx.wdx",assoc];
assoc
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me on Windows 8.1

Comment: No problem on V10.0.1, Win7-64

Comment: No problem here either, same setup as Sjoerd.  By the way do you realize that your use of `CreateTemporary[]<>".mx"` is making two files, one with the `.mx` suffix and one without?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for pointing that out; didn't occur to me.

Comment: No such side effect for me, on MMA 10.0.1.0, OS X 10.9.4. (sorry I do not have enough reputation yet to post this as a comment)